# VS Code isn't detecting python3 in Pop OS

Tags: python3, visual-studio-code

I have installed VS Code in Pop OS 20.04. Previously I worked in Ubuntu 18 with VS Code without any problem. But in Pop OS, after installing the python plugin VS Code is telling me to select a Python interpreter without auto detecting it. I have tried selecting both Python and Python3.8 from /usr/bin but still VS Code is showing telling me to select a Python interpreter.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What happens when you open the terminal and run `sudo update-alternatives --config python` and then select python 3?

Comment: This output is shown after running the command: 
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python.
There's in python2 pre-installed in Pop OS 20.04. Only python 3.8.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/installing-python-interpreters)? I haven't used VSC in a while.